# How can i assign "x-axis" title and insert greek letter "δ" in "titles" in subplot of "plotly"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, linechart, subplot

I made this graph in R with "plotly" as subplot with the following codes, but i need to make 2 changes which i cannot figure out even though i tried.

1. I don't get "title" for" x-axis" as one common for all 3-yaxis.
2. I want to put "greek letter" Delta symbol instead of writing as "d".
3. I do not know how can I make 18 as power of "O" like small 18 on top of "O".

```
p1 = plot_ly(test1, x = H_B, y = GV7_d18O_B) %>%
  add_lines(name = "δ18O_B") %>%
  layout(yaxis = a)

p2 = plot_ly(test1, x = `Iso_H(we)_D`, y = Iso_d18O_D) %>%
  add_lines(name = "δ18O_D") %>%
  layout(yaxis = b)

p3 = plot_ly(test1, x = `Iso_H(we)_E`, y = Iso_d18O_E) %>%
  add_lines(name = "δ18O_E") %>%
  layout(yaxis = c)

subplot(p1, p2, p3, nrows = 3, shareX = TRUE, margin = 0.05) %>%
  layout(main = "GV7_δ18O vs Depth (cm.we)")
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible code, so that we can try it to help you.

Comment: Wecome to stackoverflow. To get quick help here, it's best to give a small sample of your data or use one of the built in datasets to simulate your problem. This article can show you how to give a copy of your data as code:
https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html